# How to setup Atom to allow - as a click selection?

Tags: text-editors, atom-editor

For example I have the variable or element `my-app` I want to be able to double click anywhere in that word to select it whole. At the moment if you click on the `my`, it will only select `my`, and same with `app`.

[image]

I'm able to do this in the Sublime Text preferences with the following:

`"word_separators": "./\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah just found it in settings :)

[image]